# Unable to display string

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am having following code.

```
package lab1;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.DefaultMetalTheme;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel;

public class Snake extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JPanel jp;
private JFrame jf;

public Snake() {

    initlookandfeel();

    jf = new JFrame();
    jf.setVisible(true);
    jf.setBounds(200, 200, 500, 500);
    jp = new JPanel();
    jp.setVisible(true);
    jf.setContentPane(jp);
    jp.setLayout(null);
    jp.setBounds(0, 0, jf.getWidth(), jf.getHeight());
    jf.setTitle("NIRAV KAMANI");
    jp.repaint();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    Snake sn = new Snake();
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {

    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.drawString("NIRAV KAMANI", 50, 50);

}

public void initlookandfeel() {
    String lookandfeel;
    lookandfeel = "javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel";

    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(lookandfeel);
        MetalLookAndFeel.setCurrentTheme(new DefaultMetalTheme());
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new MetalLookAndFeel());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("" + e);
    }

}
}
```

I know that i am making some mistakes related to JPanel or JFrame. But i am unable to understand what's the mistake i am doing?And why? I think that there is something like one layer is overridden by another so the string is not displayed.But what i have to do if i want to display String inside JPanel?

Comment: You are extending the JFrame and also creating a new jframe inside. And the overridden method is working on the `snake` class Jframe not the one you have created inside `snake`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason you're having problems is the frame that is displaying on the screen isn't the one you think you're painting to...

Basically, you created a new class that extends from a `JFrame`

```
public class Snake extends JFrame {
```

The completely ignored it in your constructor...

```
public Snake() {

    initlookandfeel();

    // I'm a new instance of a JFrame which has nothing to do with the
    // instance of Snake...
    jf = new JFrame();
    jf.setVisible(true);
    jf.setBounds(200, 200, 500, 500);
    jp = new JPanel();
    jp.setVisible(true);
    jf.setContentPane(jp);
    // Bad idea, JFrame uses a `BorderLayout` anyway, which will do the job you want
    jp.setLayout(null);
    // Bad idea
    // The frame contains a border, possibly a menu bar and other components.  The
    // visible size of the frame will actually be smaller then it's size...
    jp.setBounds(0, 0, jf.getWidth(), jf.getHeight());
    jf.setTitle("NIRAV KAMANI");
    jp.repaint();

}
```

Now.  Before you fire up your editor to make corrections, let's see if we can make it even better...

1. Use a layout manager.  Makes life easier.
2. You're overriding the `paint` method of a top level container, this is, generally a bad idea and you found it one of the reasons why.  A frame has a lot on it, normally, it has a `JLayeredPane` and a content pane, but you've also added another panel ontop of it.
3. You should avoid extending from top level containers.  This will make your components more re-usable and flexible, as you're not locking yourself into deployment requirement...

Instead.  Make your self a custom component, say extending from something like `JPanel`, override it's `paintComponent` method and perform you custom painting there.

You should AWLAYS call `super.paintXxx` as the paint methods are chained together, failing to call one could greatly mess up the paint process, leaving artifacts and remnants of other painted components on it...

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

**Update with Example**

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class CustomPainting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CustomPainting();
    }

    public CustomPainting() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            String text = "Hello world";
            int x = (getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
            int y = ((getHeight() - fm.getHeight()) / 2) + fm.getAscent();
            g2d.drawString(text, x, y);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Understood some aspects like i am extending JFrame and creating Jframe manually which means i am doing same thing twice am i right?

Comment: Kind of. You're basically shadowing one instance of another, which is why you're getting confused.  Don't forget, also, top level containers are not double buffered, which may also impact performance, hence one of the reasons why we suggest you avoid painting to top level containers

Comment: Can you tell me what corrections i needed to paint string in JPANEL? And one more point i am unable to understand what happens when i am extending this GUI classes? I think i am simply doing inheritance then how it's possible that i am creating two different frame? I am having some understanding but not clear. thanks. Can you help me out to make it clear?

Comment: The reason you're creating two frames is, you extended from `JFrame` in your `Snake` class.  So when you do `new Snake()`, you've made your first. But then in the constructor of the class, you create a brand new one `jf = new JFrame();`.  This has nothing to do with your `Snake` class at all, so anything you've added to snake will not appear on the screen, this includes your painting...

Comment: when i put only following code in constructor it is still unable to display string.It shows the frame but it does not show string. initlookandfeel();
  setVisible(true);
  setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);
  setTitle("NIRAV KAMANI");

Comment: Ya! i understood thanks.But one more thing why you created one more class for JPanel?i think that is my main problem? it is not possible to use only one class?

Comment: Not recommended.  Best to do you custom painting on a `JComponent` of some kind, they're double buffered and don't come with the same baggage as `JFrame`